# getting unobtrusive validation result with jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, unobtrusive-javascript, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using unobtrusive validation in my form in a MVC Project. Should the unobtrusive validation fail I need to popup something in the screen and if it pass I close the form.

Now my question is how can I find out the result of unobtrusive validation on the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to the form's submit event using jQuery. When the form gets submitted you can check if it is [valid](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Plugins/Validation/valid&redirect=no), if it isn't then you can popup the dialog.

```
var form = $('#yourform');
form.submit(function() {
    if(!form.valid()) {
        alert('The form is not valid!!');
    }
});
```